# Site operator gets real IP when I do "torsocks curl example.org/file.zip"?

Tags: torsocks, torify

Quote from Reddit

> One thing, though: Don't think Torsocks is a jail. It's not even close. Applications can reach clearnet if they're explicitly trying.

I download files with:

```
torsocks curl example.org/file.zip
```

How example.org can see my real IP if only using `curl`?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried your example, it doesn't see my real ip. There maybe some clever way to bypass torsocks, but usually applications access regular API's and curl definitely doesn't leak IP's on regular requests. Also, curl doesn't leak dns in this case, only using tor with `--socks5` and not `--socks5-hostname` does.

Comment: torsocks intercepts libc calls, so any program that doesn't link to libc (for example Go programs) will bypass torsocks.

Answer (score 1):

For just a cURL - no, **but** a web browser or other application can launch another one that will make unproxified request and that's how the data leaks, so be careful in what you're doing!